# Reference for application of the theory of weights and weight-spaces to $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ and $\mathfrak{su}(3)$

Tags: reference-request, lie-algebras, root-systems

In the last couple of weeks I've been reading  [J.E. Humphreys' "Introdcution to Lie Algebras and Representation Theory"](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387900537) and after finishing Chapter 3 I had a chat with my TA about the topics*. He told me to read up on the examples of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ and $\mathfrak{su}(3)$ to see an application of the theory to some simple cases. The suggested reading material are relevant sections from [Georigi's "Lie Algebras in Particle Physics"](https://www.crcpress.com/Lie-Algebras-In-Particle-Physics-from-Isospin-To-Unified-Theories/Georgi/p/book/9780738202334).
I tried reading some chapters from Georgi's book today and I must admit that I don't understand anything that he writes. I can of course recognize similar patterns and formulas, but I don't see myself really gaining a better understanding of the concepts of roots, weights, etc. by reading his book.

*I'm therefore asking for a reference that discusses in a bit more detail the concept of Weights, Weight spaces and the root system (root diagram and simple roots) of the two Lie algebras $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ and $\mathfrak{su}(3)$.*

*) The topics covered up to this point where the necessary theory for the classification theorem of semisimple Lie algebras via Dynkin diagrams (aka Ideals, Nilpotency, Solvability, Root systems, etc.) and also Weights and Weight spaces.

Comment: The book by [Fulton and Harris](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387975276) has a lot of details. Also the book by [A. W. Knapp](https://link-springer-com.uaccess.univie.ac.at/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-2453-0).

Comment: Have you gone over the detailed description of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ in Humphreys' book?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft If you mean section 7, where he classifies all the irreducible modules of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$, then yes.

Comment: @DietrichBurde To make sure I'm thinking of the right sections here: Do you mean the chapters where he discusses the representations of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$ and $\mathfrak{sl}_3(\mathbb{C})$?